# Upadate progressdialog message

Tags: android

I have one `AsyncTask` and I am setting message of `ProgressDialog` within `onPreExecute()` method. Now I want to update message of `ProgressDialog` within method which is called from  `StartUpload()` method of `doInbackground`.

```
class performBackgroundtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       // @Override
        public void onPreExecute()
        {


            connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProcessReportsUploadActivity.this);
            connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading data...");

            connectionProgressDialog.show();

        }

       // @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {

                StartUpload();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

       // @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
            connectionProgressDialog.cancel();

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onProgressUpdate` 
 invoked on the UI thread after a call to `publishProgress(Progress...).` The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
      //set prograss to your prograss dialoglike this
      connectionProgressDialog.SetProgress(progress);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use publish progress in DoInBackground

```
 publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
```

and update progess bar in onProgressUpdate

```
/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
```

Comment: I tried, but publishProgress() is called only once. I want to update message periodically in method which is declared in StartUpload() method.

Comment: use  publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)); in your while loop

Comment: how to call  publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)); in StartUpload() method?

Comment: Is there any other way, because I cant move code in do  in background. There are many methods, switch cases... inside StartUpload() .